# Съезжающий <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css

Возможно вопрос покажется банальным, а может я просто не умею гуглить, но все же. Каким образом возможно при клике или ховере на `<div>` сдвинуть его таким образом, чтобы он частично ушел за пределы родителя, как при свайпе чата в telegram или viber? И возможно ли сделать это на чистом css. 
Вот пример (криво, но вроде-бы понятно): 
[image: Собственный макет]

Пример из Telegram: 
[image: Telegram]

Разметка `<div>`:

```html
<div class="todoitem clicked">
 <label class="label">
     <input  class="label__checkbox" type="checkbox" />
     <span class="label__text">
        <span class="label__check">
          <i class="fa fa-check icon"></i>
        </span>
     </span>
   </label>
 <div class="definition">
  <input type="text" name="todoTitle" readonly="true" class="title" value="Todo title 1">
  <textarea rows="2" cols="41" readonly="true"  maxlength="123" name="todoDescription" class="description">Todo description 2 sdgsdgsdg sg sdg sdg sdgs dg sdgsd gsdg sdg sd gsd gsd gg </textarea>
  <div class="id">id:  c - h72gsb32 - 0000 - udoc - l363eofy</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Заранее благодарю всех за ответы :)

Comment: Родителю задать overflow: hidden а сам элемент сдвигать свойством transform: translateX() или translateY() смотря в какую сторону двигать... Если я правильно понял вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение, при наведении на квадрат, круг плавно сместиться вниз

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: -25px;
  background: #f00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.wrapper:hover .block {
  transform: translateY(50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```